# What is the difference between st_isvalid and st_issimple?

Tags: geometry, postgis

In Postgis there are two very similar functions. One is [st_isValid](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/validity.html), the other one is [st_isSimple](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsSimple.html). I'd like to understand the difference between both for Polygons. For the st_isValid we have:

> Some of the rules of polygon validity feel obvious, and others feel arbitrary (and in fact, are arbitrary).
>
> - Polygon rings must close.
> - Rings that define holes should be inside rings that define exterior boundaries.
> - Rings may not self-intersect (they may neither touch nor cross one another).
> - Rings may not touch other rings, except at a point.

For the st_isSimple we've got:

> Returns true if this Geometry has no anomalous geometric points, such as self intersection or self tangency. For more information on the OGC's definition of geometry simplicity and validity, refer to "Ensuring OpenGIS compliancy of geometries"

Does it mean that any valid polygon is automatically simple?

Comment: Yes, a valid polygon (or MultiPolygon) is also simple.  The definition of simplicity is more useful for LineString inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both functions check for *similar* OGC definition compliancy of geometries, but are **defined for different geometries** (by dimension);

By OGC definition

- a **`[Multi]LineString`** can (*should*) be **simple**
- a **`[Multi]Polygon`** can (*should*) be **valid**

This implies that

- a *simple* `[Multi]LineString` is always **considered valid**
- a *valid* `[Multi]Polygon` is always **considered simple** (as in, it must have at least one *simple* closed `LineString` ring)

thus **the answer is yes**.

---

Strictly speaking, using the inherent checks of the OGC defined functionality on the 'wrong' geometry type is useless.

**PostGIS, however, liberally extends the functionality of `ST_IsValid` to use the correct checks for all geometry types**.